# redirect non-www to www on Application_BeginRequest - facing loop

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, vb.net, redirect, response

I try to redirect non www to www:

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(Object sender, EventArgs e)
 {   
   if (!Request.Url.Host.StartsWith("www"))
   {
       var path = Request.Url.Scheme+"://www." + Request.Url.Host + Request.Url.PathAndQuery;
      Response.Clear();
      Response.StatusCode = 301;
      Response.StatusDescription = "Moved Permanently";
      Response.AddHeader("Location", path);
      Response.End();
   }
 }
```

During requesting http://TestDomain.com, It's redirect to:

http://TestDomain.com/www.TestDomain.com/www.TestDomain.com/www.TestDomain.com/www.TestDomain.com/www.TestDomain.com/www.TestDomain.com/www.TestDomain.com/www.TestDomain.com/www.TestDomain.com/www.TestDomain.com/www.TestDomain.com/www.TestDomain.com/www.TestDomain.com/www.TestDomain.com/www.TestDomain.com/www.TestDomain.com

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using [RedirectPermanent](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.httpresponse.redirectpermanent?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#System_Web_HttpResponse_RedirectPermanent_System_String_System_Boolean_) and pass true the the optional parameter to terminate the request.

```
Response.RedirectPermanent(path, true);
```

> This method overload also provides the option to specify whether to
> terminate or to complete the response after the redirection has been
> performed.